# I want to get rid of a partition in a 1TB drive in ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: partitioning

here is a noob who is confused.  I purchased a 1TB HDD to use as a backup drive.
I couldn't figure which drive was the 1TB as it shows as only 488GB.
I disconnected all other drives, except the main boot drive and 2 CD drives, then rebooted the computer.
The main drive, or boot drive, is shown on the task bar as 101GB, yet using gparted it shows as 368GB..?  I know I partitioned it to add Ubuntu 64BIT system, but the gparted program shows a few different things, again..?
I only use the 1TB for backups and I wish to delete any partition on it and get back the full 1TB again.  I wish I could figure out how to show the screen shots to show the reports.  I am sure the Linux community can work out what I am trying to achieve, if not show me a step by step way of adding the screen shots.
Thank you all in advance for any help.
Rod. J.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the drive selected in GParted, in the toolbar at the top, there's a `Device` dropdown. Select `Create partition table`. From there, select the `msdos` option in the dropdown. Then you'll have the full drive unformatted in its full size. From there, in the main part of the window, right click on the unformatted disk and select `New`.
[image]

From there, name your disk, and select a format for the drive. I suggest leaving it as Ext4, but using NTFS is also just fine, especially if you want more seamless Windows compatibility. 
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  This seems to have added a second partition to the HDD.  I am trying to get rid of all partitions, then format the drive as a single 1TB drive.  Any further information is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Ah, so this is something to do with the GPT formatting. If you want to avoid this, use the MSDOS option, and you shouldn't have any issue ;) I'll edit the original answer.

Comment: Thank you Schyken, being Linux I didn't know I had the option of using an MSDOS program.  I will wait for your answer (edited) before doing anything else.

Comment: You're welcome :) It's already been edited. Same steps except for the one. ;)